# How to create multiple tests for a function using sys.argv in pytest

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I have a function that looks like this:

```
import argparse
import sys


def execute():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    if (total_args := len(sys.argv)) == 1:
        do_stuff()
    if total_args == 2:
        first = sys.argv[1]
        do_stuff2()
    if total_args == 3:
        first, second = sys.argv[1:3]
        do_stuff3()
    if total_args > 3:
        first, second = sys.argv[1:3]
        del sys.argv[1:3]
        add_args(parser)
        parser.parse_args()
        do_stuff4()
```

Which should have a test function `test_execute` that will try different given args, the question: is there a clean way to do it without manually modifying `sys.argv` using `sys.argv.extend(some_test_args)` and delete the args later?

**Note:** I can't use `argparse` optional positional arguments by setting `nargs=?` in `parser.add_argument()` because the first 2 arguments are optional and each case (1, 2, 3, > 3 arguments) executes different functions. To understand further, please check the example below ...

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('arg1', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('arg2', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_known_args()
print(args)
```

which if called like the following, will result to the wrong variable saved in the second position:

```
>>> python my_script.py --unknown-arg 999
```

Will print:

```
(Namespace(arg1='999', arg2=None), ['--unknown-arg'])
```

which is totally not what I need. I'm expecting `arg1` to have a `None` value. The reason sometimes there will be unknown arguments is that `argparse` does not support parsing arguments by specifying a group. Let's say I have argument group `A` and argument group `B` and I need to parse only group `A`, I can't do `parser.parse_group('A')` I will have to create `parser_a = argparse.ArgumentParser()` and add group `A` arguments and parse them and repeat for `parser_b`.

Therefore the best solution I have so far is using `sys.argv` despite the fact this is inconvenient for testing. Also adding all options without grouping, will create another problem because group `B` arguments depend on values parsed from group `A`.

One workaround is to specify using `--unknown-arg=999` but this will create inconsistencies in the documentation and usage of the script and is also not what I need.

Comment: `args =parser.parse_args(sys.argv[3:])`.  More generally call `parse_args(argv)`, and create or manipluate the list `argv` as you want.

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your problem, but have you thought about using a [sub-parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)?     Sub-parsers allow you to create "commands" with separate arguments, comparable to `git init --bare` where `--bare` only relates to `init`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you pass in `sys.argv` into `execute()`?

Something like this:

```py
import argparse
import sys

def execute(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    if (total_args := len(argv)) == 1:
        do_stuff()
    if total_args == 2:
        first = argv[1]
        do_stuff2()
    if total_args == 3:
        first, second = argv[1:3]
        do_stuff3()
    if total_args > 3:
        first, second = argv[1:3]
        del argv[1:3]
        add_args(parser)
        parser.parse_args(argv)
        do_stuff4()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute(sys.argv)
```

In your tests you could then do something along the lines of:

```py
def test_execute():
    test_argv = ["some", "args", "list"]

    execute(test_argv)
    # assert something
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing anyway, thanks.